# Math.Acos not working?

Tags: c#, math

When I run my program I am trying to use Cosine inverse. So I use Math.Acos().

I do:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Acos(0.8).ToString());
```

I am suppose to get the value around: 36.869897645844

but instead I am getting the value: 0.643501108793284

Is there something wrong with the method Math.Acos?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Acos%280.8%29 says 0.6435 radians.  Are you expecting degrees? (multiply by `180 / Pi`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the value to degrees

```
Console.WriteLine((Math.Acos(0.8)*(180/Math.PI)).ToString());
```

This should fix your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing is wrong, you are getting your answer in radians.

Convert it to degrees.

```
Math.Acos(0.8) * 180/Math.PI
```

Comment: How do I convert to degrees?

Comment: @GriffinMite Answer has been updated so you can see how to convert. It is simple Math.